# How can I find the fault location when using /GS security checks?

Tags: visual-c++

How can I find out where a Visual C++ security check is failing on a remote computer?

I have been brought on to a project to assist and am using the Visual Studio 2013 which has the /GS security checks to spot buffer overflows. This is great, and I don't want to turn them off, but they are causing the software to "crash" on a particular computer and I am struggling to find a way to know where. The normal tools to trap and log exceptions cannot be used. Dr Watson appears to be no longer supported, and I cannot remote debug to the computer.

I would appreciate a pointer to the appropriate tool to learn what the stack was when it failed the security check. Thank you.

Comment: /GS violations are treated like malware attacks.  Instant crash to the desktop, anything else would provide the malware a hook to do something nasty.  Only way to diagnose them is by attaching a debugger.  It automatically breaks the program just before process termination.  The call stack shows where the violation occurred.  If you can't remotely debug the machine then that's the end of it, you'll have to leave it up to the client's IT staff.  With of course non-zero odds that this machine is in fact a target of a malware attack :)

Comment: You can [enable local crash dump creation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx) on the target machine.  Once you have a crash dump, /GS failures are usually straightforward to diagnose.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Are the dumps usable in Visual Studio in some manner? That sounds like the solution if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Hans and James, the answer is as follows:

First, on the remote machine that is having the problem, enable the mini-dump for the executable. Details are in [Collecting User-Mode Dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps?redirectedfrom=MSDN) but in essence is to create a key for the name

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
DumpFolder = REG_EXPAND_SZ "c:\Path\To\Folder"
DumpCount = REG_DWORD 0x00000001
DumpType = REG_DWORD 0x00000002
```

So with that done, have your secure application crash, and you get a .dmp file in that folder.

Okay, now you have to make use of it in Visual Studio. This is quite easy too. Fully described in [Post-Mortem Debugging Your Application with Minidumps and Visual Studio .NET](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1934/Post-Mortem-Debugging-Your-Application-with-Minidu) (don't worry about the .Net part, that's not relevant), you just do a file open in Visual Studio (with no other project open, and not opening a solution but a file), and select the Dump files type. Open the file, and it has a "Run" item shown in the IDE. That opens the file as it was when it failed, and shows the exception type. The call stack for your module is all shown, and that should be enough of a clue to know where it went bang, and how to fix it.

Good luck!